# gce startup startup-script not firing

Tags: python, google-compute-engine

I have the following startup script variable defined in my python script:

```
default_startup_script = """
#! /bin/bash
cd ~/git/gcloud;
git config --global user.email "my.email@gmail.com";
git config --global user.name "my.name";
git stash;
git pull https://user:pw@bitbucket.org/url/my_repo.git;
"""
```

and the following config:

```
    config = {
      "name": "instance-bfb6559d-788f-48b7-85a3-8ff3ab6e5a60",
      "zone": "projects/username-165421/zones/us-east1-b",
      "machineType": "projects/username-165421/zones/us-east1-b/machineTypes/f1-micro",
      "metadata": {
        "items": [{'key':'startup-script','value':default_startup_script}]
      },
      "tags": {
        "items": [
          "http-server",
          "https-server"
        ]
      },
      "disks": [
        {
          "type": "PERSISTENT",
          "boot": True,
          "mode": "READ_WRITE",
          "autoDelete": True,
          "deviceName": "instance-4",
          "initializeParams": {
              "sourceImage": "projects/username-165421/global/images/image-id",
              "diskType": "projects/username-165421/zones/us-east1-b/diskTypes/pd-standard",
              "diskSizeGb": "10"
          }
        }
      ],
      "canIpForward": False,
      "networkInterfaces": [
        {
          "network": "projects/username-165421/global/networks/default",
          "subnetwork": "projects/username-165421/regions/us-east1/subnetworks/default",
          "accessConfigs": [
            {
              "name": "External NAT",
              "type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "description": "",
      "labels": {},
      "scheduling": {
        "preemptible": False,
        "onHostMaintenance": "MIGRATE",
        "automaticRestart": True
      },
      "serviceAccounts": [
        {
          "email": "123456-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
          "scopes": [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Now - the instance creates without issue, but the startup script does not fire.

I am creating the instance by running:

```
compute.instances().insert(
        project=project,
        zone=zone,
        body=config).execute()
```

All of the samples were retrieved from [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript).

Once the instance is created and I paste my startup script manually it works without issue.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. My issue was related to user accounts. I was not logging in as the default user (**Eg**: `username@instance-id`).

If you are reading this question just be sure of which username you are intending to run this for and manage accordingly.